# Convert time and date from one time zone to another in PHP

Tags: php, timezone

Basically what I need is an script that, when provided with a time and a timezone can return the time in another time zone.

My main issues are:

- Where to get the time offset from GMT from - is there a public database available for this?
- How to also take into consideration the daylight saving time (DST) differences as well.
- How to nicely wrap it all up inside an PHP class - or is there such a class already available?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Chatham'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
?>
```

The above examples will output:

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00+12:00
2000-01-01 01:45:00+13:45
```

found on [DateTime Manual on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)

EDIT:
Like Pekka said: The DateTime class exists from 5.2 on and there you first have to find out which of the methods are realy implemented and which one only exist from 5.3 on.

Comment: Beat me to the punch, deleting mine. It's worth mentioning that DateTime is available since PHP 5.2 - there is a patch for 5.1 but it's experimental

Comment: Yep. datetime is pretty "new". Even in 5.2 it doesn't contain all the functions that are needed, wanted and mentioned in the manual

Comment: Good answer. These functions automatically handle daylight saving too, where simply adding an offset is clunky and inaccurate.

Comment: Perfect! Such a simple answer to an otherwise important question.

Answer (score 22):

try this, it might help :)

```
function converToTz($time="",$toTz='',$fromTz='')
    {   
        // timezone by php friendly values
        $date = new DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone($fromTz));
        $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($toTz));
        $time= $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        return $time;
    }
```

**A bit description:**
The function takes 3 inputs, time to convert, timezone to convert to, current timezone and returns the output in the specified format.

Comment: Nice, thank you! Example usage: `echo converToTz('2021-08-20 15:47:00', 'Europe/London', 'UTC');`

Answer (score 3):

I know its late. For anyone who would want simple function to convert utc to any local time zone

```
function UTCTimeToLocalTime($time, $tz = '', $FromDateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $ToDateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
if ($tz == '')
    $tz = date_default_timezone_get();

$utc_datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat($FromDateFormat, $time, new
    DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$local_datetime = $utc_datetime;

$local_datetime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($tz));
return $local_datetime->format($ToDateFormat);
}

 echo UTCTimeToLocalTime('2015-07-01 13:30:00','America/Denver');
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert from the given timezone to the desired timezone, we just have to add/subtract the difference of timezones (in SECONDS) to given timezone.

```
$my_timestamp = strtotime("2020-09-22 14:07:26");
/*
 Convert timezones difference into seconds
 from -7:00 to +5:30  have 12hrs and 30min difference
 So in seconds, 12.5*60*60 is equaled to 45000 seconds
*/

$time_zone_difference = 45000;

//Use date function to get datetime in your desired formate
echo date("Y-m-d h:i:sa", $my_timestamp + time_zone_difference );
```

or we can write it like
Below given functions are for additional help.

Convert timezone differences in seconds, (which you can hardcode, if it is fixed throught the project):

```
function timezoneDifferenceInSec( $source_timezone, $required_timezone){
    $a = explode(":",$source_timezone);
    $b = explode(":",$required_timezone);
    $c = (intval($a[0])*60+intval($a[1]))*60;
    $d = (intval($b[0])*60+intval($b[1]))*60;
    $diffsec =0;
    if($c < $d)
        $diffsec = $d-$c;
    else
        $diffsec = $c-$d;
    return $diffsec;
    }

//function call
$differenc = timezoneDifferenceInSec("-07:00", "+05:30");
```

Function to convert DateTime into required Timezone (if difference is known):

```
 //datetime in String and timezone_differe is in int
function convertTimezone( $source_date_time,  $timezone_diff_in_sec){
    return date("Y-m-d h:i:sa", strtotime($source_date_time) + $timezone_diff_in_sec);
 }

 //function call
 $timestamp = "2020-09-22 14:07:26";
 $timezone_difference = 4500; //ie from -07:00 to +05:30

 echo convertTimezone( $timestamp, $timezone_difference);
```

Comment: Downvoted.  As this approach doesn't take Daylight saving into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Function to convert DateTime into required Timezone (if difference in seconds among the timezones is known):
example: Timestamp give is "2020-09-22 14:07:26".
Timezones difference in seconds id 4500; //ie from -07:00 to +05:30

```
 // timestamp as in String and timezones_diff_in_sec is in int
function convertTimezone( $timestamp,  $timezones_diff_in_sec){
    return date("Y-m-d h:i:sa", strtotime($source_date_time) + $timezones_diff_in_sec);
 }
```

Function call (

```
 //function call
 $timestamp = "2020-09-22 14:07:26";
 $timezone_difference = 4500; //ie from -07:00 to +05:30

 echo convertTimezone( $timestamp, $timezone_difference);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here i use this function for converting datetime into another timezone.
For best result if you convert your datetime into utc timezone and then convert into required timezone then it is better result for it.

```
function ConvertTimezoneToAnotherTimezone($time, $currentTimezone, $timezoneRequired) {
    $dayLightFlag = false;
    $dayLgtSecCurrent = $dayLgtSecReq = 0;
    $system_timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
    $local_timezone = $currentTimezone;
    date_default_timezone_set($local_timezone);
    $local = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    /* Uncomment if daylight is required */
    //        $daylight_flag = date("I", strtotime($time));
    //        if ($daylight_flag == 1) {
    //            $dayLightFlag = true;
    //            $dayLgtSecCurrent = -3600;
    //        }
    date_default_timezone_set("GMT");
    $gmt = date("Y-m-d H:i:s ");

    $require_timezone = $timezoneRequired;
    date_default_timezone_set($require_timezone);
    $required = date("Y-m-d H:i:s ");
    /* Uncomment if daylight is required */
    //        $daylight_flag = date("I", strtotime($time));
    //        if ($daylight_flag == 1) {
    //            $dayLightFlag = true;
    //            $dayLgtSecReq = +3600;
    //        }

    date_default_timezone_set($system_timezone);

    $diff1 = (strtotime($gmt) - strtotime($local));
    $diff2 = (strtotime($required) - strtotime($gmt));

    $date = new DateTime($time);

    $date->modify("+$diff1 seconds");
    $date->modify("+$diff2 seconds");

    if ($dayLightFlag) {
        $final_diff = $dayLgtSecCurrent + $dayLgtSecReq;
        $date->modify("$final_diff seconds");
    }

    $timestamp = $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s ");

    return $timestamp;
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: What is this over-engineered mess?  Why are you blending DateTime Objects with `strtotime()` in the same function?