# Convert Timestamp to Timezones

Tags: php, timezone

I have a timestamp the user enters in GMT.

I would then like to display that timestamp in gmt, cet, pst, est.

Thanks to the post below I have made, which works perfectly!

```
public static function make_timezone_list($timestamp, $output='Y-m-d H:i:s P') {

    $return     = array();
    $date       = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp));
    $timezones  = array(
        'GMT' => 'GMT', 
        'CET' => 'CET', 
        'EST' => 'EST', 
        'PST' => 'PST'
    );

    foreach ($timezones as $timezone => $code) {
        $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($code));
        $return[$timezone] = $date->format($output);
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Lookup the timezone offsets relative to GMT and add that to your current timestamp in GMT.

Comment: perfect answer for timezone...

http://stackoverflow.com/a/3905222/1266559

Comment: Came here through Google. The example in your question is the same as the accepted answer (it uses DateTIme), I don't understand what is the question since you say "It's working perfectly". Also I don't understand why you accepted an answer that is doing exactly the same thing as the code in your question.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You could use PHp 5's [`DateTime` class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php). It allows very fine-grained control over Timezone settings and output. Remixed from the manual:

```
$timestamp = .......;


$date = new DateTime("@".$timestamp);  // will snap to UTC because of the 
                                       // "@timezone" syntax

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "<br>";  // UTC time

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Chatham'));   
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "<br>";  // Pacific time

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "<br>";  // Berlin time
```

Comment: Will this handle day light saving also.?  Or we dont have to care about that, just time difference is needed!

Comment: @zod it will handle DST as well.

Comment: ateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (1438929689) at position 8 (8): Unexpected character