# Get Zenith value and GMT Offset by IP, latitude and longitude

Tags: php, timezone, latitude-longitude, timezone-offset

I want to use **date_sunset** and **date_sunrise** php's functions but the result is not accurate .. I have the user's IP, Longitude, Latitude and i googled how to calculate **Zenith** value but found nothing.

And the final value in those functions is **GMT Offset** that i couldn't get it also.

This is available values that i can get for any client and want to use it to get **Zenith** and **GMT Offset** ..

```
geoiprecord Object (

   [country_code] => EG
   [country_code3] => EGY
   [country_name] => Egypt
   [region] => C
   [city] => Cairo
   [postal_code] => 
   [latitude] => 30.0771
   [longitude] => 31.2859
   [area_code] => 
   [dma_code] => 
   [metro_code] => 
   [continent_code] => AF
   [region_name] => Cairo Governorate
   [timezone] => Africa/Cairo

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just leave the `$zenith` and `$gmt_offset` parameters at their defaults.  The result of these functions is an integer timestamp which is in terms of UTC.  Simply convert the result to the time zone you have in your data `"Africa/Cairo"`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4186922/634824) for a good example of how to convert timestamp to a specific time zone in PHP.