# DateTime and time zones when calling Facebook PHP SDK?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, datetime, time, timezone

My time zone is `Europe/Rome`. I'm using **Facebook PHP SDK** and [insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/) part of the API accepts a parameter `end_time` relative to [Pacific Daylight Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Time_Zone):

> The end of the period during which the metrics were collected,
>   expressed as a unix time (which should always be midnight, Pacific
>   Daylight Time).

**Question** is fair simple: should i convert `$end` to PDT (and how) before calling `getTimeStamp()` in order to get correct stats for my time zone?

```
// Get stats with 1st January 2012 as end_time (relative to my time zone)
$page  = Facebook->getUser()->getPage($id);
$stats = $page->getData('page_views_unique', new DateTime('2012-01-01')); 

public function getData($metric, DateTime $end = null)
{
   $now = new DateTime();
   $end = is_null($end) || $end > $now ? $now : $end; // Default is $now

   // API call
   $args = array('end_time' => $end->getTimestamp());
   $this->sdk->api(sprintf('/%s/insight/%s', $this->id, $metric), 'GET', $args);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Convert time and date from one time zone to another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905193/convert-time-and-date-from-one-time-zone-to-another-in-php)

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
?>
```