# Generating week start and end dates with timezone offset

Tags: php, date, strtotime, timezone-offset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert time and date from one time zone to another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905193/convert-time-and-date-from-one-time-zone-to-another-in-php)

I have two variables which show the weeks start and end date as follows:

```
$week = strtotime('-' . date('w') . ' days');
$start = date('Y-m-d', $week);
$end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+6 days', $week));
```

How can I offset these dates for a different timezone (e.g. PST?)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905193/convert-time-and-date-from-one-time-zone-to-another-in-php.

Answer (score 1):

This will convert a tie in your servers timezone to the given timezone.

```
$datetime = new DateTime;
$newTZ  = new DateTimeZone('Your/TimezoneHere');
$datetime->setTimezone($newTZ);
```

Comment: Very good, only he's not using `DateTime` objects at the moment. You may want to explain a bit more about it.