# how to convert time in ny to utc zone

Tags: php, timezone, utc, datetime-conversion

How to convert given time in NY zone into UTC zone by php. I will give only the time not date ( ex. 12:30 am ). I wants to convert the given time into UTC time like ( 05:30 am ).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505681/timezone-conversion-in-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905193/convert-time-and-date-from-one-time-zone-to-another-in-php

Comment: @AmitRajput in the example they converted by using both date and time, but in my query i have used only time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [`gmdate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) function of PHP instead like as

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
echo $script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();
$ny_time = "12:30 am";
echo gmdate('h:i a',strtotime($ny_time));// 05:30 am
```

> [`gmdate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) is identical to the [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function except that the time returned is Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/hHThD)

Comment: Does this take into account the effects of Daylight saving time?

Answer (score 2):

As Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) is 5 hours ahead of New York (NY), NY, USA. So you just need to add 5 hours to convert your NY time to UTC like below:

```
<?php
    $ny_time = "12:30 am";
    $utc_time = strtotime("+5 hours", strtotime($ny_time));
    echo date('h:i a', $utc_time); // output 05:30 am
?>
```