# Converting from UTC to any timezone

Tags: php, datetime

My linux box is set to use UTC.  Given a timezone and a date, I want to get the date range so that I can query the database for records created on any given day.  For instance, if it is now 2018-03-24 at 9am in America/Denver timezone.  I want to get the start and end times for this date in UTC.  How can I get the UTC equivilant of the beginning of that date?

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), new     DateTimeZone('America/Denver'));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
?>
```

this returns 2018-03-24 00:00:00 which is not correct.  Any pointers?

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); on top of your PHP script. and all the dates you create are UTC

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905193/convert-time-and-date-from-one-time-zone-to-another-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this function.

```
 function UTCTimeToLocalTime($time, $tz = '', $FromDateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $ToDateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
    if ($tz == '')
        $tz = date_default_timezone_get();

    $utc_datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat($FromDateFormat, $time, new
        DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    $local_datetime = $utc_datetime;

    $local_datetime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($tz));
    return $local_datetime->format($ToDateFormat);
}

echo UTCTimeToLocalTime('2015-07-01 13:30:00','America/Denver');



function LocalTimeToUTCTime($time, $tz = '', $FromDateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $ToDateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
    if ($tz == '')
        $tz = date_default_timezone_get();
    $utc_datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat($FromDateFormat, $time, new
        DateTimeZone($tz));
    $local_datetime = $utc_datetime;
    $local_datetime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    return $local_datetime->format($ToDateFormat);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thank you!

Comment: I believe the function name should be called LocalTimeToUTC though.  If I pass it a local time (2018-03-24 00:00:00) it will return the UTC time, right?  2018-03-23 18:00:00

Comment: I need to get the datetime range of any given date.  If today is 2018-03-24 in Americal/Denver time I need the UTC times back so I can query the database for this dates records.  In UTC this would need to be 2018-03-23 18:00:00 to 2018-03-24 17:59:59.

Comment: i have edited my answer and use the local to utc function

Comment: If I pass in 2018-03-24 00:00:00 to your new function it returns 2018-03-24 06:00:00  the first function actually gives me back the correct UTC time of 2018-03-23 18:00:00

Comment: The function names need to be switched in order for them to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You feed the `DateTime` constructor with a bogus local time:

```
new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), newDateTimeZone('America/Denver'));
             ^^^^
```

You tell PHP that's a Denver local time but you don't really know. Since the string does not contain time zone information PHP will use the [default time zone](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone).

Just drop `date()`. It serves no purpose and only makes things harder.

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/Denver'));
echo $date->format('r'), PHP_EOL;
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $date->format('r'), PHP_EOL;
```

```
Sun, 25 Mar 2018 06:11:21 -0600
Sun, 25 Mar 2018 12:11:21 +0000
```